# Python abstract decoration not working

Tags: python, abstract-class

I was coding a decoration (for curiosity's sake) to make a class abstract in python. So far it looked like it was going to work, but I got an unexpected behavior.

The idea for the decoration looks like this:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

def abstract(cls):
    cls.__metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    return cls
```

Then, when using this decoration, it's only needed to define a abstract method

```
@abstract
class Dog(object):
   @abstractmethod
   def bark(self):
      pass
```

But when I test, I was able to instantiate a Dog object:

```
d = Dog()
d.bark() //no errors
Dog.__metaclass__ //returned "<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>"
```

When testing assigning `__metaclass__` directly, it behave as expected:

```
class Dog(object):
   __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
   @abstractmethod
   def bark(self):
      pass
```

Testing:

```
d = Dog()

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#98>", line 1, in <module>
    d = Dog()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Dog with abstract methods bark"
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: check my answer, this solves your problem. Thanks for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce your problem.

**ABCMeta.__new__ is never called** using your decorator. When you really define it as metaclass of Dog, it gets called. This is because the Dog class has already been defined, so adding ABCMeta after won't actually make any difference, because its **new** not being called at definition time, won't register the Dog class as an abstract and won't discover its abstract methods. I invite you to read the ABCMeta.**new** code and you'll see what it does.

However, I found this solution, to still make your decorator work:

```
def abstract(cls):
    return ABCMeta(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))
```

This works now as expected. Meaning that **you must subclass** `Dog` to be able to call `bark`.

Answer (score 4):

The python reference [states](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation):

> When the class definition is read, if `__metaclass__` is defined then the callable assigned to it will be called instead of type(). This allows classes or functions to be written which monitor or alter the class creation process

The important part is *when the class definition is **read***, that means you can't change the metaclass afterwards, and that's just what a decorator tries to do, as it's just syntactic sugar.

```
@some_decorator
class SomeClass(object):
    pass
```

is the same as:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    pass

SomeClass = some_decorator(SomeClass)
```

So when the decorator is called, the class definition has already been read.

Comment: Very concise answer. Although Apero's answer that gave me a solution, I would also mark yours as "accepted" if I could.